# Escape control and non-ASCII characters (high-bit) in JavaScript string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there an easy way in javascript to only escape certain ranges of control characters?

Specifically, I want to escape just the ranges "\x00-\x1f" and "\x7f-\xff" (control and high-bit characters). I need to escape only those characters before calculating a hash that is then sent to an API. The standard functions like encodeURI() and escape() escape too much.

Basically, I need to match the functionality of perl's [uri_escape($text,"\x00-\x1f\x7f-\xff")](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI/Escape.pm) .

Comment: This is very easy to do with a regular expression and using the [*replacer function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Also, don't forget about unicode characters `\u100`+!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function uri_escape( text, re ) {

    function pad( num ) {
        return num.length < 2 ? "0" + num : num;
    }

    return text.replace( re, function(v){
        return "%"+pad(v.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).toUpperCase();
    });
}

uri_escape( "\u0015\u0012", /[\x00-\x1f\x7f-\xff]/g );
//"%15%12"
```

Comment: That works great. On a related note, is there a way to have javascript convert the string of characters '\x00' to the control character \x00 so it will work with that function?

Comment: @user1007700 when you write a string like this `"\u0000"` (or `"\x00"`) it will contain the `NUL` character.

Comment: the issue is that it could be parsed from something that has them as individual characters already. Is there a way to detect strings that would represent control characters and convert them back into the control characters?

Comment: @user1007700 do you mean a string that has literally `\x00`? ( as in, result from `"\\x00"` )

Comment: Yes. For example, I want to be able to copy a malicious URL that contains \x00 and feed it into my javascript, which searches a list of known bad URL hashes. However, the known list escapes those control characters from the URL before making the hash.

Comment: @user1007700 try this `var re = /\\x([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})/g;
 var text = "\\x00";
 
 text = text.replace( re, function( whole, m1 ) {
  return String.fromCharCode( parseInt( m1, 16 ) );
 });`